# how to have mouse hold down right click in C#

Tags: c#, windows, mouse, kinect

I figured out how to have mouse right click when certain events occur(in my case Kinect skeleton data)

```
mouse_event((uint)(MouseEventFlags.RIGHTDOWN | MouseEventFlags.RIGHTUP),(uint)mousepos.X, (uint)mousepos.Y, 0, 0);
```

This code performs mouse right click only once. How can I make it so it happens longer similar to holding down my mouse right click as long as I am doing certain gesture in Kinect?

Comment: Well it's doing click with down and up), so maybe just down, and then another event just up? You know mouseevent has been superseded?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mentioned events with some timer between them.

Example:

```
MouseDown
    Start Timer
MouseUp
    Disable Timer
```

Then you can do whatever you want between timers.